# Converting JSON to CSV and CSV to JSON with custom headers Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, csv, parsing

I'm struggling to find a good way to achieve import/export features supporting csv format without external libraries. Anyone that could help me on that would be a lifesaver. Really!

I have a csv string which I'll refer to as "A":

```
"First Name,Last Name,Phone Number\r\nJohn,Doe,0102030405\r\nJoe,Dohn,0102030406"
```

And I have an array of json which I'll refer to as "B":

```js
[
    {
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Doe",
        phone: "0102030405"
    },
    {
        firstName: "Joe",
        lastName: "Dohn",
        phone: "0102030406"
    }
]
```

- I need to create a generic function that takes an array of objects defining headers to go from A to B
- I also need to create a generic function that takes an array of objects defining headers to go from B to A

In that specific case the array of objects defining headers would look like this:

```js
[
    {
        label: "First Name",
        key: "firstName",
    },
    {
        label: "Last Name",
        key: "lastName",
    },
    {
        label: "Phone Number",
        key: "phone",
    }
]
```

EDIT :
My actual data is a bit different and the solution of Darshan Jain is not fully working (the import works just fine but not the export). Here is my json which is actually an element of a mongoose collection:

```js
[
    {
        auxiliaryActionZones: [],
        backOfficePrivateNotes: [],
        _id: 60003b0ac20b224a58976294,
        id: 'acf7660c-4277-4b40-8e99-c00445daf755',
        status: 'Candidat',
        inactivityStartDate: null,
        inactivityEndDate: null,
        firstName: 'Marcus',
        lastName: 'CASTO',
        dateOfBirth: null,
        avatarURI: '',
        phone: '+33601020304',
        email: 'marcus@gmail.com',
        address1: 'Rue de Paradis',
        address2: '',
        city: 'Paris',
        postalCode: '75010',
        location: '',
        companyLegalStatus: 'Auto-entrepreneur',
        companyAddress1: 'Some address',
        companyAddress2: '',
        companyCity: 'Paris',
        companyPostalCode: '75000',
        companyLocation: '',
        companyName: 'Entreprise CASTO',
        companySiren: '',
        companyInstitutionCode: '',
        companyKbisURI: '',
        companyNic: '',
        companyRcs: '',
        companyHasVAT: true,
        companyIntracomVATCode: '',
        companyVATRate: '',
        bic: '',
        iban: '',
        contractURI: '',
        contractAppendicesURI: '',
        billingMandateURI: '',
        selfBillingMandateURI: '',
        insurancePolicyURI: '',
        doesBirthShootings: false,
        doesBabyAndChildrenShootings: false,
        doesFamilyShootings: false,
        doesPregnancyShootings: false,
        doesNurseryAndSchoolShootings: false,
        experienceYears: '',
        canShootAtClientHome: false,
        canShootOutside: false,
        canShootInStudio: false,
        website: '',
        instagram: '',
        facebook: '',
        hasDigitalReflex: false,
        hasCobraFlash: false,
        hasStudioKit: false,
        hasPregnancyAccessories: false,
        hasBirthAccessories: false,
        cameras: '',
        lens: '',
        selfPresentation: '',
        additionalComment: '',
        availableTime: '',
        isMovingByFoot: false,
        isMovingByBicycle: false,
        isMovingByPersonalVehicle: false,
        isMovingByPublicTransportation: false,
        actionZone: 10,
        creationDate: 2021-01-14T12:37:30.862Z,
        lastModificationDate: 2021-01-14T12:37:30.862Z,
        applicationValidationDate: null,
        memberAcceptanceDate: null,
        __v: 0
    },

]
```

When I try to export it it gives with the following headers:

```js
[
    {
        label: 'Identifiant',
        key: 'id'
    },
    {
        label: 'Statut',
        key: 'status'
    },
    {
        label: 'Date de début d\'inactivité',
        key: 'inactivityStartDate'
    },
    {
        label: 'Date de fin d\'inactivité',
        key: 'inactivityEndDate'
    },
    {
        label: 'Prénom',
        key: 'firstName'
    },
    {
        label: 'Nom',
        key: 'lastName'
    },
    {
        label: 'Date de naissance',
        key: 'dateOfBirth'
    },
    {
        label: 'Mobile',
        key: 'phone'
    },
    {
        label: 'Email',
        key: 'email'
    },
    {
        label: 'Mot de passe',
        key: 'password'
    },
    {
        label: 'Confirmation de mot de passe',
        key: 'passwordConfirmation'
    },
    {
        label: 'Adresse ligne 1',
        key: 'address1'
    },
    {
        label: 'Adresse ligne 2',
        key: 'address2'
    },
    {
        label: 'Adresse Code postal',
        key: 'postalCode'
    },
    {
        label: 'Adresse Ville',
        key: 'city'
    },
    {
        label: 'Localisation',
        key: 'location'
    },
    {
        label: 'Type structure',
        key: 'companyLegalStatus'
    },
    {
        label: 'Nom entreprise',
        key: 'companyName'
    },
    {
        label: 'Entreprise ligne 1',
        key: 'companyAddress1'
    },
    {
        label: 'Entreprise ligne 2',
        key: 'companyAddress2'
    },
    {
        label: 'Entreprise Code postal',
        key: 'companyPostalCode'
    },
    {
        label: 'Entreprise Ville',
        key: 'companyCity'
    },
    {
        label: 'Entreprise Localisation',
        key: 'companyLocation'
    },
    {
        label: 'Siren',
        key: 'companySiren'
    },
    {
        label: 'Code établissement',
        key: 'companyInstitutionCode'
    },
    {
        label: 'Soumis à la TVA',
        key: 'companyHastVAT'
    },
    {
        label: 'Taux TVA',
        key: 'companyVATRate'
    },
    {
        label: 'Code TVA Intracommunautaire',
        key: 'companyIntracomVATCode'
    },
    {
        label: 'BIC',
        key: 'bic'
    },
    {
        label: 'IBAN',
        key: 'iban'
    },
    {
        label: 'Contrat',
        key: 'contractURI'
    },
    {
        label: 'Annexes contrat',
        key: 'contractAppendicesURI'
    },
    {
        label: 'Police d\'assurance',
        key: 'insurancePolicyURI'
    },
    {
        label: 'Mandat d\'autofacturation',
        key: 'selfBillingMandateURI'
    },
    {
        label: 'Entreprise Localisation',
        key: 'companyLocation'
    },
    {
        label: 'Expérience Naissance',
        key: 'doesBirthShootings'
    },
    {
        label: 'Expérience BB/Enfant',
        key: 'doesBabyAndChildrenShootings'
    },
    {
        label: 'Expérience Famille',
        key: 'doesFamilyShootings'
    },
    {
        label: 'Expérience Grossesse',
        key: 'doesPregnancyShootings'
    },
    {
        label: 'Expérience Crèche/Ecole,',
        key: 'doesNurseryAndSchoolShootings'
    },
    {
        label: 'Années d\'expérience',
        key: 'experienceYears'
    },
    {
        label: 'Site internet',
        key: 'website'
    },
    {
        label: 'Compte Instagram',
        key: 'instagram'
    },
    {
        label: 'Page facebook',
        key: 'facebook'
    },
    {
        label: 'Présentez-vous',
        key: 'selfPresentation'
    },
    {
        label: 'Commentaires',
        key: 'additionalComment'
    },
    {
        label: 'Commentaires LSDP',
        key: 'backOfficePrivateNotes'
    },
    {
        label: 'Reflex numérique',
        key: 'hasDigitalReflex'
    },
    {
        label: 'Flash cobra ou équivalent',
        key: 'hasCobraFlash'
    },
    {
        label: 'Kit studio photo portable',
        key: 'hasStudioKit'
    },
    {
        label: 'Accessoires photos pour séance grossesse',
        key: 'hasPregnancyAccessories'
    },
    {
        label: 'Accessoires photos pour séance naissance',
        key: 'hasBirthAccessories'
    },
    {
        label: 'Boitier',
        key: 'cameras'
    },
    {
        label: 'Objectif',
        key: 'lens'
    },
    {
        label: 'Shootings au domicile clients',
        key: 'canShootAtHome'
    },
    {
        label: 'Shootings en extérieur',
        key: 'canShootOutside'
    },
    {
        label: 'Shootings dans votre propre studio',
        key: 'canShootInStudio'
    },
    {
        label: 'Disponibilités temps de travail',
        key: 'availableTime'
    },
    {
        label: 'A pied',
        key: 'isMovingByFoot'
    },
    {
        label: 'A vélo',
        key: 'isMovingByBicycle'
    },
    {
        label: 'Voiture scooter',
        key: 'isMovingByPersonalVehicle'
    },
    {
        label: 'Transports public',
        key: 'isMovingByPublicTransportation'
    },
    {
        label: 'Rayon d\'action',
        key: 'actionZone'
    },
    {
        label: 'Zones géographique auxiliaires',
        key: 'auxiliaryActionZones'
    },
    {
        label: 'Voiture scooter',
        key: 'isMovingByPersonalVehicle'
    },
    {
        label: 'Voiture scooter',
        key: 'isMovingByPersonalVehicle'
    },
    {
        label: 'Voiture scooter',
        key: 'isMovingByPersonalVehicle'
    },
    {
        label: 'Date de création',
        key: 'creationDate'
    },
    {
        label: 'Date de dernière mise à jour',
        key: 'lastModificationDate'
    },
    {
        label: 'Date de validation du dossier complet',
        key: 'applicationValidationDate'
    },
    {
        label: 'Date d\'activation du dossier',
        key: 'memberAcceptanceDate'
    },
]
```

````
"Identifiant,Statut,Date de début d'inactivité,Date de fin d'inactivité,Prénom,Nom,Date de naissance,Mobile,Email,Mot de passe,Confirmation de mot de passe,Adresse ligne 1,Adresse ligne 2,Adresse Code postal,Adresse Ville,Localisation,Type structure,Nom entreprise,Entreprise ligne 1,Entreprise ligne 2,Entreprise Code postal,Entreprise Ville,Entreprise Localisation,Siren,Code établissement,Soumis à la TVA,Taux TVA,Code TVA Intracommunautaire,BIC,IBAN,Contrat,Annexes contrat,Police d'assurance,Mandat d'autofacturation,Entreprise Localisation,Expérience Naissance,Expérience BB/Enfant,Expérience Famille,Expérience Grossesse,Expérience Crèche/Ecole,,Années d'expérience,Site internet,Compte Instagram,Page facebook,Présentez-vous,Commentaires,Commentaires LSDP,Reflex numérique,Flash cobra ou équivalent,Kit studio photo portable,Accessoires photos pour séance grossesse,Accessoires photos pour séance naissance,Boitier,Objectif,Shootings au domicile clients,Shootings en extérieur,Shootings dans votre propre studio,Disponibilités temps de travail,A pied,A vélo,Voiture scooter,Transports public,Rayon d'action,Zones géographique auxiliaires,Voiture scooter,Voiture scooter,Voiture scooter,Date de création,Date de dernière mise à jour,Date de validation du dossier complet,Date d'activation du dossier\r\n,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,\r\n,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,\r\n,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For converting CSV to JSON:

```
let csvData ="First Name,Last Name,Phone Number\r\nJohn,Doe,0102030405\r\nJoe,Dohn,0102030406";

let headers = [
  {
    label: "First Name",
    key: "firstName"
  },
  {
    label: "Last Name",
    key: "lastName"
  },
  {
    label: "Phone Number",
    key: "phone"
  }
];

const convertCsvToJson = (csvData, headers) => {
  let tempCsvData = csvData.split("\r\n");
  let csvToJson = [];
  if (tempCsvData && tempCsvData.length > 0) {
    let inputHeaders = tempCsvData[0].split(",");
    //To find out the required headers on which position.
    for (let i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
      const header = headers[i];
      let index = inputHeaders.indexOf(header.label);
      if (index > -1) {
        header.index = index;
      } else {
        //Since It is not present in CSV
        headers.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
    for (let i = 1; i < tempCsvData.length; i++) {
      const temp = tempCsvData[i].split(",");
      let jsonData = {};
      for (let j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
        const header = headers[j];
        if (temp[header.index]) {
          jsonData[header.key] = temp[header.index];
        }
      }
      csvToJson.push(jsonData);
    }
  }
  return csvToJson;
};

console.log(convertCsvToJson(csvData, headers));
```

For converting JSON to CSV:

```
let jsonData = [
  {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    phone: "0102030405"
  },
  {
    firstName: "Joe",
    lastName: "Dohn",
    phone: "0102030406"
  }
];

let headers = [
  {
    label: "First Name",
    key: "firstName"
  },
  {
    label: "Last Name",
    key: "lastName"
  },
  {
    label: "Phone Number",
    key: "phone"
  }
];
const convertJsonToCsv = (jsonData, headers) => {
  // To avoid any errors
  let jsonToCsv = "";
  if (jsonData && jsonData.length > 0 && headers && headers.length > 0) {
    // Adding columns names to the csv as it should be the starting point
    for (let i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
      const header = headers[i];
      jsonToCsv += header.label || "";
      if (i < headers.length-1) {
        jsonToCsv += ",";
      }
    }
    jsonToCsv+='\r\n'
    for (let i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
      const temp = jsonData[i];
      for (let j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
        const header = headers[j];
        jsonToCsv += temp[header.key] || "";
        if (j < headers.length-1) {
          // If we dont keep this condition it will add ',' to the last column also which we dont need.
          jsonToCsv += ",";
        }
      }
      if (i < jsonData.length-1) {
        jsonToCsv += "\r\n";
      }
    }
  }
  return jsonToCsv;
};

console.log(convertJsonToCsv(jsonData, headers));
```